# Migration from leaflet 0.7 to 1.0

Tags: javascript, migration, leaflet

I'd like to upgrade leaflet from 0.7 to 1.0 (rc1) but I get a lot of errors due to API changes. Is there a migration guide or some information I could use to to that ?

Thank you

Comment: You are right there does not seem to be a "migration guide" for the Leaflet 0.7 => 1.0 transition. Feel free to post your code to get some help, and once you completed your migration, to share your findings with the community! I am sure such a guide would deserve a good place on Leaflet website.

Comment: There is some info in here: http://leafletjs.com/2016/04/18/leaflet-1.0-rc1.html and maybe there is more on such a blog posts

Comment: changelogs may help https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md